# What version of Perforce am I using?

Tags: perforce

What version of Perforce `p4.exe` am I using? I tried various commands, but none worked :(

```
> p4 --version
Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: --version.

> p4 version
Unknown command.  Try 'p4 help' for info.
```

but none worked. So, how can I tell what version of Perforce `p4.exe` I am using?

---

For comparison:

```
> git --version
git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0

> hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.6.1)
```

Comment: Try `p4 -V`. http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_info.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
> p4 -V

Perforce - The Fast Software Configuration Management System.
Copyright 1995-2014 Perforce Software.  All rights reserved.
This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project
for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit (http://www.openssl.org/)
See 'p4 help legal' for full OpenSSL license information
Version of OpenSSL Libraries: OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
Rev. P4/NTX64/2014.1/807760 (2014/03/18).
```